# Ndarray from Numpy.genfromtxt is a 1D array of 1D arrays, not 2D

Tags: python, numpy

*Changed to a smaller example because StackEx could not display the 281 long examples.

I have used np.genfromtxt to load 8997 rows with 18 columns into an ndarray but it made a 1D array with 8997 rows.

data[0] prints the first row

data[0][0] the first element

data[0,0] prints the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    data[0,0]
IndexError: too many indices for array

Can I transform it into a 2D ndarray? Why doesn't genfromtxt create a 2D naarray?

If this helps,

len(data[0]) = 18 but data[0].shape returns "()".

So, genfrontxt is detecting each and every element per line but storing them as one row. Is there an elegant way to convert this 1D array into an 8997 x 18 2D array?

Edits for reference:

The load commands:

data = np.genfromtxt(filepath.replace('.dfn', '.dat'), dtype = None, names = csvnames)

data = np.genfromtxt(filepath.replace('.dfn', '.dat'), dtype = None, names = csvnames,  delimiter = widths)

I used both and got the same ndarray. I feed in a list of column names. Using the fixed widths did not change the result. I let the function determine datatypes, which it does fine.

Data properties

data.shape (8997,)

First line of the data file - (first column is the string value DATA)

```
DATA  190010.0  1284   4 190010 1783000 20170122   0 131.000035 -31.255325 119016.47 6535194.03  58.55  62.06  987.22  22.61  55076.69  10476.91   8155.08 57238.0957 57238.6536 58639.18 57795.78
```

First row from ndarray -> data[0]

```
(b'DATA', 190010., 1284, 4, 190010, 1783000, 20170122,   0, 131.000035, -31.255325, 119016.47, 6535194.03, 58.55, 62.06, 987.22, 22.61, 17830.  , 133.71)
```

data.type

```
[('COMM', 'S4'), ('FLTLINE', '<f8'), ('Project', '<i4'), ('Flight', '<i4'), ('Line', '<i4'), ('Fid', '<i4'), ('YYYYMMDD', '<i4'), ('Bearing', '<i4'), ('Long', '<f8'), ('LATITUDE', '<f8'), ('EAST', '<f8'), ('NORTH', '<f8'), ('RadAlt', '<f8'), ('LasAlt', '<f8'), ('Press', '<f8'), ('Temp', '<f8'), ('GPSTime', '<f8'), ('GPSHt', '<f8')]
```

Comment: Show us `data.shape` and `data.dtype`.  Also, what was the `genfromtxt` command?  (especially what was the `delimiter` and the `dtype` parameters).

Comment: You have a structured array, 1d for the rows, fields corresponding to columns in the file.  Field names appear in the `dtype`.  Alternatively you might want to load this as a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Thanks hpaulj. Pandas read_csv is the answer.